# Did any other countries try to breed a race out like what happened in Australia?

Tags: australia, aboriginals

In Australia's History, the Europeans tried to breed out Aboriginals colour by pairing a Aboriginal Woman with a White Man. They did this because they believed...

1. That Aboriginals were a dying race
2. That Australia was a 'white mans' country
3. If they did this than if they had a baby it would be a quarter white and so on until the black colour was gone

My question is did any other countries do this and was this an effect of Transnational History. This happened around about the time of the Stolen Generation in about the 1909's 1969 I think.

Answers are appreciated.

Comment: The premise of this question should be backed up by stronger evidence. Are you saying that *some* Europeans *may* have paired *one* aboriginal woman with *one* white man against their will? Why is it that the circumstances seem relatively unclear but the ascribed reasons are not? As it now stands, the chosen title does not seem to match the body of this (perhaps [loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)) question.

Comment: The Aboriginal Woman was forced. Why the European man? And shouldn't the evidence come in the answer?

Comment: @Drux The concept of "breeding out the colour" was a concept that [did](http://www.stolengenerations.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=140&Itemid=109) exist in Australia. However, in at least some jurisdictions and times, sex between aboriginal and non-aboriginal people was illegal except with special permission, so "breeding out the colour" wasn't a universally agreed-upon policy.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm alright, that helps: I can Google it not. But I think this kind of information should really go into the question, because not everybody (esp. outside Australia) has the required background knowledge.

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence of policies to force marriage of Aborigines with whites. There were certainly policies in place to prevent them from marrying certain people that the department deemed inappropriate, but that's a different thing.

Comment: It wasn't marriage!!!! Try not reading between the lines.

Comment: @lins314159 I don't think the Australian government forced any white men to have sex with, or marry, Aboriginal women. I'd also note that in many countries with concepts of "racial superiority", men from "superior races" were willing to have sex with "racially inferior" women.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm just for clarification: I can google it noW (earlier typo)

Comment: @MiharuDante IMHO you should really work on improving your question (esp. its premise) based on the comments received: I'm (also) at a loss understanding what the "1909's 1969" might refer to.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Nanking Massacre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre) and [war rape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_rape) in general; see also book title: *The Rape Of Nanking: The Forgotten Holocaust Of World War II*.

Comment: Given the high level of commentary interest, and rapid commentary, and the politicised nature of this historical issue, I have protected the question.

Comment: This isn't really about breeding, but a fellow Australian might find this interesting. The Maori people of New Zealand today are actually not the original inhabitants. The islands were before peopled by short (maybe pygmy like) tribes. The Maori invaded and were then cannibals, so they actually hunted and ate them to extinction!

Comment: The website I cited, called stolengenerations.info, is arguing against the academic consensus that there was a stolen generation. I'd advise people not to trust it. [This article](http://www.themonthly.com.au/nation-reviewed-robert-manne-comment-keith-windschuttle-2256), agreeing with the academic consensus, also refers to "breeding out the colour".

Answer (score 1):

The section "Former Yugoslavia" of the Wikipedia article on [War rape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_rape#Former_Yugoslavia) says that Serbs raped Muslims and Croatians with the intention to produce new Serbs

> During the Bosnian War the existence of deliberately created "rape
>   camps" was reported. The reported aim of these camps was to impregnate
>   the Muslim and Croatian women held captive. It has been reported that
>   often women were kept in confinement until the late stage of their
>   pregnancy. **This occurred in the context of a patrilineal society, in
>   which children inherit their father's ethnicity, hence the "rape
>   camps" aimed at the birth of a new generation of Serb children.**
>   According to the Women's Group Tresnjevka more than 35,000 women and
>   children were held in such Serb-run "rape camps".[152][153][154]

However, when this was happening, large-scale, systematic killing on racial or religious lines also was happening.

I'm not sure if this answers the question, because I assume the question asker is mainly interested in attempts at eliminating a race without large-scale killing being done.

Comment: The concept of *race* (Bosnian as opposed to other war parties) perhaps does not apply here, or does it?

Comment: @Drux it doesn't. It wasn't so much racial as religious. Muslims raping Christians, Christians Muslims. It's age old and simply showing domination over a subjected population by the most base mean possible, the violation of its women.

Comment: @jwenting I agree (hint: rhetorical question).

Comment: @Drux does it matter whether it's a race or a religious group?